# $ a \cos A + b \cos B + c \cos C = \dfrac{a+b+c}2 $ $\implies$ the triangle is equilateral?

Tags: trigonometry

If in a triangle $ a \cos A + b \cos B + c \cos C = \dfrac{a+b+c}2 $ , then is the triangle equilateral ?

Answer (score 1):

This  is a 1990 Russian maths contest problem

$\cos A=\dfrac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}$, so

$$a \cos A + b \cos B + c \cos C = \dfrac{a+b+c}2 $$

$$\Longleftrightarrow$$

$$a^4+b^4+c^4-2(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2)+abc(a+b+c)=0\tag{1}$$

There are several ways to show (1)

In fact

$$a^4+b^4+c^4-2(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2)+abc(a+b+c)$$

$$=(a+b+c)\Big(abc-(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)\Big)$$

It is easy to show that

$$abc-(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)=0\Longleftrightarrow a=b=c$$

**another method to prove (1)**

one can use Schur's inequality

$$\sum a^2(a-b)(a-c)\geq0$$

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle a=2R\sin A\implies\cos A=R(\sin2A)$

$\displaystyle\implies\sum a\cos A=R(\sum\sin2A)$

Using [Prove that $\sin(2A)+\sin(2B)+\sin(2C)=4\sin(A)\sin(B)\sin(C)$ when $A,B,C$ are angles of a triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154505/prove-that-sin2a-sin2b-sin2c-4-sina-sinb-sinc-when-a-b-c-are),  $\displaystyle\sum a\cos A=4R\prod\sin A=4R\prod2\sin\frac A2\cos\frac A2$

Again, $\displaystyle\frac{a+b+c}2=R(\sum \sin A)$

Using [this](http://www.goiit.com/posts/list/trignometry-sina-sinb-sinc-4cosa-2cosb-2cosc-2-1053264.htm),  $\displaystyle\frac{a+b+c}2=4R\prod\cos\frac A2$

As $\displaystyle0<A,B,C<\pi\implies\cos\frac A2$ (etc.) $\ne0,$ the problem reduces to $\displaystyle\prod2\sin\frac A2=1$

$\implies4\sin\frac A2\left(\cos\frac{B-C}2-\cos\frac{B+C}2\right)=1 $

As $\displaystyle B+C=\pi-A\implies \frac{B+C}2=\frac\pi2-\frac A2$

$\displaystyle\iff4\sin^2\frac A2-4\sin\frac A2\cos\frac{B-C}2+1=0 $ which is a Quadratic Equation in $\sin\frac A2$

As $A$ is real the discriminant  $\displaystyle\left(4\cos\frac{B-C}2\right)^2-4\cdot4=-16\sin^2\frac{B-C}2$ must be $\ge0$

$\displaystyle\implies\sin^2\frac{B-C}2=0\iff\cos(B-C)=1-2\sin^2\frac{B-C}2=1\implies B-C=2n\pi $

As $\displaystyle0<B,C<\pi\implies B=C\implies\sin\frac A2=\frac12$

Can you prove $A=60^\circ?$

Answer (score 0):

If you use the relation, $a=2R sin A$,

I have not got the solution, however, I can help in solving this:

$$\sin 2A.\sin 2B. \sin 2C= 4 \sin A \sin B \sin C$$ (can be easily derived using $C=\pi-A-B$)

Then

$$\sin A.\sin B. \sin C=4 \cos (A/2).\cos (B/2).\cos (C/2)$$

Using $$\sin A=2\sin (A/2) \cos (A/2)$$, we get, $$\sin (A/2) \sin (B/2) \sin (C/2)=\frac{1}{8}$$

Now in a triangle,

$$\sin (A/2) \sin (B/2) \sin (C/2)\leq \frac{1}{8}$$ (which can be proved using partial derivatives, assuming $A=x$, $B=y$ and $C=\pi-x-y$, but I think there has to be a simpler proof than this)

And the equality holds only in case of equilateral triangle, hence, the triangle has to be equilateral!

Hence proved.
[This discussion](http://functionspace.org/topic/1441) will surely help you in solving this!