# $\sin x+\sin y+\sin z=4\cos\frac{x}{2}\cos\frac{y}{2}\cos\frac{z}{2}$

Tags: trigonometry

If $x+y+z=\pi$ how to prove that $\sin x+\sin y+\sin z=4\cos\frac{x}{2}\cos\frac{y}{2}\cos\frac{z}{2}$?

I got that $\sin x+\sin y+\sin z=2\sin\frac{x+y}{2}\cos\frac{x-y}{2}+\sin x\cos y+\sin y\cos x$ and I don't know what to do next.

Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2149333/42969.

Comment: Another one https://math.stackexchange.com/q/608307

Answer (score 0):

[I hope you this helps with the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w74qy.png)

=2*sin⁡((x+y)/2)* cos⁡((x-y)/2)+2*sin⁡(z/2)*cos⁡(z/2)
=2*sin⁡((π-z)/2)* cos⁡((x-y)/2)+2*sin⁡((π-(x+y))/2) *cos⁡(z/2)
=2*cos⁡(z/2)*cos⁡((x-y)/2)+2*cos⁡((x+y)/2)*cos⁡(z/2)
=2*cos⁡(z/2)*[cos⁡((x-y)/2)+cos⁡((x+y)/2)]
=2*cos⁡(z/2)*[2*cos⁡(x/2)*cos⁡(y/2)]
=4*cos⁡(x/2)*cos⁡(y/2)*cos⁡(z/2)

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your answers. As it stands this is not readable.

Comment: It is not advisable to answer a question that has already been signaled as a duplicate (I should say multiplicate).