# A problem in Trigonometry (Properties of Triangles) v2

Tags: trigonometry

Please help me with this sum:

> In any triangle ABC, prove that $$a^2 b^2 c^2 \left (\sin {2A} +\sin {2B} + \sin {2C} \right) = 32 \Delta ^3$$

Here $\Delta  $ means the area of the triangle.

My attempts:

[image]

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154505/prove-that-sin2a-sin2b-sin2c-4-sina-sinb-sinc-when-a-b-c-are  and  
 (https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Area_of_Triangle_in_Terms_of_Circumradius
 or https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h345932s1_prove_that_abc4r__abc)

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee it doesn't help at all.

Comment: Have you noticed the answer, how it is linked with the links I've supplied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that

1. $\sin 2A + \sin 2B + \sin 2C = 4\sin A\sin B\sin C$
2. $bc\sin A = 2\Delta$

So, $$LHS = 4(bc\sin A)(ca\sin B)(ab\sin C) = 32 \Delta^3.$$