# If $\sin^{-1}(x)+\sin^{-1}(y)+\sin^{-1}(z)=\pi$ then prove that $x*\sqrt{1-x^2}+y*\sqrt{1-y^2}+z*\sqrt{1-y^2}=2xyz$

Tags: trigonometry

I assumed $\sin^{-1}(x)=A$, $\sin^{-1}(y)=B$ and $\sin^{-1}(z)=C$.

Then it went the following way

$ A + B + C = \pi$

$A + B = \pi - C$

$\sin(A+B)= \sin(\pi-C)$

$\sin A \cos B + \cos A \sin B = sin C$

$x\sqrt{1-y^2}+y\sqrt{1-x^2} = \sin(\sin^{-1}(z))$

Am i right in doing so or heading wrong?

Comment: Wlcome to Math StackExchange. Please use MathJax to make your formulas clearer.

Also, the formula you've given is not true, thus it cannot be proven. Please check if it's correctly written.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154505/prove-that-sin2a-sin2b-sin2c-4-sina-sinb-sinc-when-a-b-c-are