# Prove that: $a^3\cos{B}\cos{C} + b^3\cos{C}\cos{A} + c^3\cos{A}\cos{B} = abc(1-2\cos{A}\cos{B}\cos{C}).$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

In $\Delta ABC$, prove that: $$a^3\cos{B}\cos{C} + b^3\cos{C}\cos{A} + c^3\cos{A}\cos{B} = abc(1-2\cos{A}\cos{B}\cos{C}).$$

I know that $$a^3\cos{(B-C)}+b^3\cos{(C-A)}+ c^3\cos{(A-B)}=3abc$$ and $$\cos^2{A}+\cos^2{B}+\cos^2{C} + 2\cos{A}\cos{B}\cos{C}=1.$$ Can these two results be used to prove the statement above? Any kind of help/suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Expand $\cos(x-y)$s and use law of sines.

Answer (score 1):

$$a^3\cos{(B-C)}+b^3\cos{(C-A)}+ c^3\cos{(A-B)}=3abc$$ gives
$$\sum_{cyc}a^2\frac{\cos B}b\frac{\cos C}c+\sum_{cyc}a^2\frac{\sin B}b\frac{\sin C}c=3.$$
By law of sines, i.e., $\frac{\sin A}{a}=\frac{\sin B}{b}=\frac{\sin C}{c}$, we have
$$\sum_{cyc}a^2\frac{\cos B}b\frac{\cos C}c+\sum_{cyc}a^2\frac{\sin^2 A}{a^2}=3,$$
i.e.
$$\sum_{cyc}a^2\frac{\cos B}b\frac{\cos C}c+\sum_{cyc}(1-\cos^2 A)=3$$
$$\sum_{cyc}a^2\frac{\cos B}b\frac{\cos C}c-\sum_{cyc}\cos^2 A=0$$
$$\sum_{cyc}a^3\cos B\cos C=abc\sum_{cyc}\cos^2 A$$
and the title identity follows now by using the second identity you gave:
$$\cos^2{A}+\cos^2{B}+\cos^2{C} + 2\cos{A}\cos{B}\cos{C}=1.$$

Comment: Thanks, man .

Answer (score 0):

Hints: By sine-law, $a=2R\sin A$, $b=2R\sin B$, and $c=2R\sin C$, where
$R$ is the radius of the circumcircle of the triangle $\Delta ABC$.
Writing $a,b,c$ in terms of $\sin A,\sin B,\sin C$ and cancelling
the $R^{3}$ on both sides, the expression reduces to another expression
involving $\sin A,\sin B,\sin C,\cos A,\cos B,\cos C$ only. Further
write $C=\pi-A-B$, we can reduce the expression so that it contains
$\sin A,\sin B,\cos A,\cos B$ only. Now, $A$ and $B$ are essentially
not restricted. Therefore, we can anticipate that the expression arises
from some trigonometric identities involving two variables.

Answer (score 0):

$$2a^3\cos B\cos C=a^3(\cos(B-C)+\cos(B+C))=a^3\cos(B-C)-a^3\cos A$$

$$a^3\cos A$$
$$=(2R)^3\sin^3A\cos A$$
$$=2R^3(2\sin^2A)\sin2A$$
$$=2R^3(1-\cos2A)\sin2A$$
$$=2R^3(\sin2A)-R^3(\sin4A)$$
Use [Prove that $\sin(2A)+\sin(2B)+\sin(2C)=4\sin(A)\sin(B)\sin(C)$ when $A,B,C$ are angles of a triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154505/prove-that-sin2a-sin2b-sin2c-4-sina-sinb-sinc-when-a-b-c-are) for $\sin2A+\sin2B+\sin2C=4\sin A\sin B\sin C$

Use [this](https://www.sarthaks.com/643736/prove-that-sin4a-sin4b-sin4c-4sin2a-sin2b-sin2c) for $\sin4A+\sin4b+\sin4C=\cdots=-4(8\sin A\sin B\sin C)\cos A\cos B\cos C$

Can you take it from here?